# File is not folding when opened

Tags: folding

Trying to figure out why folds aren't happening as soon as I open a file:

```
set foldenable
set foldmethod=expr
let g:lastnum = 0
function! FoldFile(lnum)
    echom 'hi';
    if getline(a:lnum) =~? '\v^\s*$'
    let g:lastnum = -1
        return '-1'
    endif
    let last = g:lastnum
    let num_of_pounds = strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '^#\+'))
    if (num_of_pounds > 0)
            let g:lastnum = num_of_pounds
        if last == -1
            return '>' . num_of_pounds
        endif
        return num_of_pounds
    endif
    return g:lastnum
endfunction
set foldlevel=0
set foldexpr=FoldFile(v:lnum)
```

To get the folds to kick in, I have to source my ~/.vimrc file

Comment: Ah, dammit, a plugin is setting foldmethod to manual. How do I override this behavior?

Comment: depends on the plugin. Curious: are you sure you always want exactly this fold setup, irrespective of filetype?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm mostly focused on just getting basic stuff working at this point and trying to figure out why stuff doesn't.

Comment: Ok. So, what plugin overrides it? Have you considered putting this stuff in an after/ftplugin file? For folds i usually go with after/ftplugin/{filetype}/folds.vim

Comment: Vimwiki. I couldn't even override it because it overrides it when the buffer loads. Resorting to making a patch to the plugin (or trying to, at least): https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/pull/692

Comment: Yeah that sounds like an issue in the plugin.